# Access violation in changing data pointed to by char *const in C++

Tags: c++

I was reading C++ hacks by Steve Qualine and its written that:

```
char *const ptr;//statement 1
```

The pointer is not affected by the const keyword, and the following is legal.

```
*ptr = 'S';//statement 2
```

But when I write the above code, the `statement 1` itself gives me error saying the pointer must be initialized and when I do initialize it, the `statement 2` gives me access violation.

What am I missing?, I ran it on Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Did you initialize the pointer?

Comment: *How* do you initialize the pointer? And if you don't initialize the pointer, it will either be a null-pointer (if the variables is declared in the global scope) or have an indeterminate (and unchanging) value (if it's a local variable). Both cases will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Show us your code. What did you make the pointer point to? If you made it pointer to a constant, of course you can't change what it points to.

Comment: "when I do initialize it". Show, don't tell.

Comment: If the book really said `char *const ptr;`, then the book is wrong

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create a variable `char *const ptr`, you need to have memory ready at declaration for it to point to. This is because the *pointer* (as opposed to the memory it points to) is const, and must be set at declaration.

This is in contrast to a `const char *`, where the memory pointed to is const, but the pointer is not, so you can change it to point to a different region of `const char` in memory, but you cannot change the memory that it points to.

Consider the following code snippet:

```
char buf[16] = "Hello World";
char *const ptr = buf;        // ptr and buf both point to "Hello World".
*ptr = 'J';                   // ptr and buf now point to "Jello World"
ptr = "Another string";       // Error, cannot assign to a variable that is const

const char *cptr = buf;       // cptr points to "Jello World".
*cptr = 'H';                  // Error, cannot assign to a variable that is const
cptr = "Another string";      // cptr now points to "Another string".
```

Comment: But why in the book its written without giving initial value?

Comment: I am not familiar with that book, so couldn't comment on the author's intention. When you say my method works, do you mean this code does compile for you? Because it doesn't compile for me (due to the error described in the comments) with either Visual Studio 2015 or GCC 4.9.2.

Comment: @What I mean is that now *ptr = 'J' does not give error.

Comment: That line should not give an error. It is allowed for `char *const ptr`. Only the lines `ptr = "Another string";` and `*cptr = 'H';` are errors.